# Suspicious GitHub mirror site (https://hzb.world/)

Tags: phishing, github

Through some odd Google rabbit hole, I ended up at what appeared to be the GitHub website. I reflexively tried logging in to view my repositories. Upon attempting to log in, it said my browser did something "odd", and the login failed.

I checked the browser URL and it had instead, at the top `https://hzb.world/`. Fearing this was some sort of phishing expedition, I immediately went and changed my password on GitHub and set up 2FA.

Googling `https://hzb.world/` came up with literally nothing. What is going on here?

Comment: It's almost certainly a phishing site. (It could be a publicly available staging site, but but this is extremely unlikely.)  You did the right thing by immediately changing your password and setting up 2FA. If you re-used that password, change it everywhere and start using a password manager.

Comment: Thank you. I have reported the website to Google as a phishing website. I checked the Whois record, but of course nothing particularly illuminating. SSL certificate is different from GitHub, so it's basically confirmed that it's a phishing website.

Comment: It's being fronted through CloudFlare; I submitted a phishing report to them as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, even if it _was_ legitimate, it'd still have a different cert -- it's a different domain. It's still pretty obviously a phishing site (you can't actually log in, it looks _just like_ the real thing, etc. -- you clearly know what the signs are) but that particular piece of evidence isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The site seems inoperable right now, but it was likely either a phishing site or a mirror.

If it were just a mirror, it's likely that the login forms were broken or else redirected to GitHub properly. However, you likely wouldn't know, so you must treat it as hostile. Your decision to change your password on the real GitHub was wise.